# How to solve this problem：AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600001071060> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46

Tags: macos, audio

I am programming a maocs desktop software. I need to read the virtual audio driver to obtain system sound.

```
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.beginConfiguration()
        do {
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
            if session.canAddInput(input) {
                session.addInput(input)
            } else {
                return
            }
        } catch {
            return
        }
        let output = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
        if session.canAddOutput(output) {
            session.addOutput(output)
        } else {
            return
        }

        let receiver = OSXAudioReceiver()
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "osx-playback.receiver")
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(receiver, queue: queue)
        session.commitConfiguration()
        session.startRunning()
```

But an error was reported

```
AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600001071060> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
HALC_ShellDevice.cpp:2,609  HALC_ShellDevice::RebuildControlList: couldn't find the control object
CMIO_DAL_PlugInManagement.cpp:913:CreatePlugIn Could not find plugin with kCMIOHardwarePlugInTypeID
HALB_MachPort.cpp:174  HALB_MachPort::DestroyPort: not going to destroy anything this way
<<<< AVCaptureInputPort >>>> Fig assert: "status == 0 " at bail (AVCaptureInputPort.m:253) - Getting connection node info to add format description property listener (err=18,446,744,073,709,551,566)
```

My real need is to have wavy lines displayed on the UI after obtaining the system sound, but the first step of obtaining the sound data cannot be achieved.

Comment: Is your app sandboxed?